# What fonts are used in the 'Biomutant' game UI

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I just saw some trailers to the game Biomutant and I really like the artwork and UI. I am wondering what font(s) are used since I'd like to use them in my own projects.

Here is a screenshot form one of the [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qubc2bIHZt8&t=92s)

[image]

Questions that come to my mind

1. What fonts are used?
2. What are free/open source fonts that i can use in my own project and a quite similar to the one shown in the image?

Comment: Your question is getting close votes because it doesn't follow the [requirements for font identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will improve the question tomorrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which specific font you mean in the screenshot, but that yellow typeface looks like [Bungee](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Bungee) Google font. There are 4-5 different styles of this typeface. You can find all in Google fonts searching for *Bungee*. Here is a screenshot from the specific font page.

[image]

This font is licensed under the [Open Font License](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=OFL).

Answer (score 0):

"Murgel is the definition" is either FF Meta or its open-source adaptation Fira Sans. It's not open-source but if you like Bungee but want a design with lower-case you might like to look at [Aglet Sans](https://xyztype.com/fonts/aglet_sans).